# Defining a recursive function calculate(a) that returns the value of the calculation and number of recusive calls as a tuple

Tags: python

I am to define a recursive function named `calculate(a)` that takes a non negative integer as parameter and returns a tuple which has the value of calculation and number of recursive calls.

The series is - `1/2 + 2/3 + 3/4 ... n/n+1`

This is what I have so far:

```
def calculate(a):
    res = 0
    if a <= 1:
        return 0.5,0
    
    n, count = calculate(a-1)
    
    return  a/a+1 + n, count + 1
```

This is how the function should run:

```
>>>res1 = calculate(1)
(0.5,0) #expected
(0.5, 0)#got

>>>res2 = calculate(2)
(1.667, 1)#expected

(2.5,1)#got

>>> res3 = calculate(7)
(5.2821, 6)#expected

(12.5,6)#got
```

Comment: Firstly, shouldn't result 2 be 1.167? Because 1/2+2/3 = 0.5+0.667 = 1.167? Also, the error is because a+1 isn't in brackets, leaving you with (a/a)+1=2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot brackets in `a/(a+n)` at return statement.

In case you don't know python follows operator precedence according to PEMDAS.
As you forgot brackets when `a=1`, `a/a+n` evaluates as `(a/a) + n` or `1 + n` which gives `2.5` as `n is 0.5` when `calculate(1)` is called during recursion.

And by the way for `a == 2` the series evaluates to `1.1667` not `1.667`.